# How to have a certain user inherit all file permissions from another user as if they were the owner

Tags: files, fedora, permissions, users, su

I just switched to Fedora 27 and was wondering if what I want is possible.

I want a certain user to inherit all permissions from another user (Meaning: Being able to access files as if I were the owner)

I'd like a structure as follows:

```
root
├── desktop_user
│   ├── firefox
│   ├── chrome
│   └── games
│       ├── game_1
│       └── game_2
└── All other applications
```

Where I want the `desktop_user` to be able to access files from all sub-users in the tree.
but `firefox` and `chrome` would not be able to act as `desktop_user`.

The same goes for `desktop_user` and `root`. I do not want to have access to `root` unless I enter a password. I am looking for a clean way to do this, preferably.

Comment: `but firefox and chrome would not be able to act as desktop_user` please explain what `act like` means here!

Comment: I do not want firefox and chrome to gain the same level of permission as the desktop user

Meaning: *su desktop_user* should fail for firefox and chrome

Comment: What is a sub-user?

Comment: I could not think of a better term for it, but it's an user which belongs to another user, see the tree above.

I want the users in the list to be able to have full control over all their children shown in the tree.

So in this case:

`game_1` is a sub-user of `games` and `games` is a sub-user of `desktop_user`

Comment: Create a group for the others and add desktop_user to it so it can act like firefox & co, then add user desktop_user to the `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo` command!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'd upvote you but unfortunately I do not have enough rep. :(
You can copy my answer, and I'll select it as the answer if you want some points

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I think I have it figured out with the help of [George Udosen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/160267/george-udosen).

I edited the sudoers rules using:
`visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/overrides`

```
desktop_user ALL=(%desktop_child) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Where `desktop_child` is the group assigned to all children in the tree from `desktop_user`.

This allows `desktop_user` to sudo all it's children, but not vice versa.

Comment: I'm confused how "sudo all" grants the user the same file permissions as another user (as per your question).

Comment: I used the set group flag on the filesystem, forcing new files into the `desktop_user` group.